# Geany keyboard shortcut for cycling through argument suggestions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, geany

I am a bit frustrated, editing a bigger C++ project with the otherwise really cool, lightweight editor Geany.

I wondered if there is a keyboard shortcut for cycling through the argument suggestions that geany shows when opening a bracket for calling a function (see image).

[image]

I could not find any shortcut for doing, what geany does when clicking on the button the mouse cursor hovers over in the shown image (that is cycling through the different constructors for - in this case - MenuButtonRect). Until now I am using the mouse for this, which interrupts the work flow a bit. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible at present however useful it might be. Looking at the Scintilla bug tracker there's a [rejected feature request for this](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/208/). Scintilla is the editor widget that Geany uses. I don't think the maintainer of Scintilla is against such a feature but he just won't implement it himself. If you're interested in adding the feature, you can contact the scintilla-interest mailing list or hit us up on the Geany mailing lists or on #geany on FreeNode IRC and we can help guide you with how to proceed getting it into Scintilla and Geany.